# Spring Integration JMS Issue

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-retry

We are using Spring Integration to consume messages from a queue and the requirement is to send the message to Error queue if there is any issue in the processing of the message consumed.
Flow works fine but one issue we see is when there is any exception thrown in processing of message, the message is redirected to the Error queue which we have configured but it is appended by the entire stack trace of the exception. 
We are looking only for the original message to be delivered to the queue. Below is the configuration we have done,

```
<bean id="errorQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${error.queue}" />
</bean>
<bean id="inQ" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${inbound.queue}" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="error" />
<int:channel id="inbound" />

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="jmsIn" channel="inbound" container="messageListenerContainer"
    acknowledge="transacted"></int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsError"
channel="error" connection-factory="mqConnectionFactory"
destination="errorQ" delivery-persistent="true"></int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>


<int:service-activator id="service"
input-channel="inbound" ref="messageListener" method="someMethodInListerner">
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession" />
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
```

```
<bean id="retryWithBackoffAdviceSession"
    class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
    <property name="retryTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
            <property name="backOffPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
                    <property name="initialInterval" value="${initialInterval}" />
                    <property name="multiplier" value="${multiplier}" />
                    <property name="maxInterval" value="${maxInterval}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="retryPolicy">
                <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
                    <property name="maxAttempts" value="${redelivery}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="recoveryCallback">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer">
            <constructor-arg ref="error" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message sent to the `error` is an `ErrorMessage` with payload `MessagingException`.

The `MessagingException` has two properties `cause` and `failedMessage`.

So, if you want to send the original failed message to `errorQ`, you will need to add a transformer to the error flow...

```
<int:transformer ... expression="payload.failedMessage" />
```

**EDIT**

```
<int:chain input-channel="error">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage" />
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter ... />
</int:chain>
```

**EDIT2**

Generally, when using these techniques, it's useful to convey the reason for the failure. You can add the exception's message as a header...

```
<int:chain input-channel="error">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="failureReason" expression="payload.cause.message" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer expression="payload.failedMessage" />
    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter ... />
</int:chain>
```

Comment: Hi Gary, added the input channel code as well now above, so it is being handled on a flow. I do understand your comment of adding a transformer to send only original payload to Error queue but where do I need to put that in the flow ?

Comment: I think adding a transformer passing the payload should work ?  <int:transformer input-channel="inbound"
  output-channel="error" 
  expression="payload"/>

Comment: A transformer with `expression="payload"` does nothing at all - see my edit.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that you were using a retry recover, but the transformer's the same because the recoverer also creates an `ErrorMessage`.

Comment: It might be useful to capture the reason for the failure and convey it as a header in errorQ.